# What does factoryClass mean in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Got these lines while working in a project automatically created by Flash Develop.
Not able to figure out what does this `[Frame(factoryClass) = "xxxx"]`  mean..

```
[Frame(factoryClass = "app.Preloader")]
```

What syntax is it following ? Is it any type of array index .. what is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that your main class will you factoryClass as preloader.
Here is article about it http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=946

Comment: and what's meant by a factory class ? I have heard Factory Mathod Design Pattern... but what's Factory class ?

Comment: factory class and factory design pattern have no correlational points. That's just mean "That frame will be called afterm factoryClass frame will workaround". Something like this.

Comment: -1. your answer should contain something informative than just a bare link